# Serving a website using Caddy

Tags: amazon-ec2, caddy, caddyfile

I have created an application and want to serve it using caddy.

On my localhost if I run the application on 127.0.0.1:9000 and set it as proxy in 
the caddyfile it works. I figured I have to serve my website similarly on my production as well.

Now I am trying to serve it on my ec2 instance. I tried serving it on localhost, 127.0.0.1 and even the domain directly itself but caddy does not work here. Oneof the things I noticed is that the url is automatically changing from http tp https, I figure it means that at least caddy is running and recognizing the request but  is not actually able to find the content.

Below is my CaddyFile.

```
abc.xyz.com {
    proxy / zbc.xyz.com:9000 {
        transparent
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Caddy does not work here"?

Comment: What I mean is, caddy does not serve the website on the ec2 instance. It gives does somehow redirect to https all the http requests(even after i stopped the process apparently.)

Comment: Be more specific: when you say that it does not serve the website, are you receiving an empty response, a 404, etc.?

Comment: It Times out.
`GET https://abc.xyz.com/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`